# libc fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at (code=1) android 4.1.1 phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I created a sample application in phonegap with cordova 2.2.0 and integrate the adMob. My problem is that it is working on all device but only crash in android 4.1.1. When I comment the admob code it works fine.. I don't know why this error occur. Give me any suggetion.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on an **Samsung Galaxy S2** with **Android 4.1.2**. It appears always by tapping a lot on html `<div>` with more than one jQuery actions.

The error disappeared by using html `<button>` instead of html `<div>`. Perhaps in the plugin adMob, there are a lot of `<div>`'s?